# How to get 2D nparray by applying different functions to each element in 1D nparray?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a length `n` numpy array, called `data`. For each element in `data`, I want to apply `k` different functions (specifically, scipy.stats.norm.pdf with k different means) and result in an `n x k` 2D numpy array. Is there a fast way to do this without looping through all the elements in `data`?

I've tried writing this with loops, but I'd like it to have better performance. Haven't been able to find any resources in documentation on how to apply multiple functions to a 1d array and expand it to a 2d nparray.

Comment: If you want all `k` of the functions evaluated in parallel, I think you'll have to look into `multiprocessing` or such. `joblib` would probably work nicely here. But I don't think `numpy` has any functionality for that. If you don't want to parallelize things, doing a loop over the `k` functions in Python shouldn't be bad. I presume that `k` is small compared to `n`; if so, you'll still be spending most of your time waiting for `numpy` / `scipy`'s computations on the array.

Comment: Can this function (for one `k` parameter) work on the whole length `n` array?  In other words, can you do the job with one loop on `k`?  What's the relative size of `n` and `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.norm` is vectorized in its parameters. You can simply do:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data,means = np.ogrid[-3:3:13j,-1:1:5j]
stats.norm(loc=means).pdf(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just replace data with your actual list:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
data = [1,2,3]
new_list = list(map(norm.pdf , data))
new_array = np.array([data, new_list])
print(new_array)
```

Output is

```
[[1.         2.         3.        ]
 [0.24197072 0.05399097 0.00443185]]
```